# 2016 Macbook Pro can no longer use recovery partition

Tags: macos, recovery, recovery-hd

I have a new MacBook Pro..so I cloned my old one Sierra 10.2.3 over to the new one. Everything worked great however now I can't use the recovery partition anymore on the new MacBook Pro. It comes up with the "no smoking" symbol in white.

The recovery partition exists....and has data in it. Just can't boot from it. Is there any easy way to restore the recovery partition?

Comment: Can you clarify: (1) Are you saying the MBP boots just fine, but if/when you want to boot into the recovery partition you have no joy? (2) How did you do the_clone_ from your old machine?

Comment: I cloned using Disk Utility on one machine and target disk on the other.
And yes I Can boot fine just not into recovery

Answer (score 1):

*Make sure you have a working backup of your data.*

Your first option is to simply reinstall macOS from [internet recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) (press cmd+option+R at startup) or an external (USB) drive.

Alternatively, [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2016/07/03/recreate-recovery-partition-mac/) describes the process of recreating the recovery partition.

> 1. Download a copy of the “Install OS X” or “Install Mac OS X” from the Mac App Store under the “Purchases” tab which matches the version of system software on your Mac (for example, the “Install OS X Mavericks” app, or “Install macOS Sierra” app)
> 2. [Go to the developers website here](http://musings.silvertooth.us/downloads-2/) and download the latest version of Recovery Partition Creator, it’s an AppleScript that will handle the recreation of the recovery drive
> 3. After the app has downloaded, right-click on “Recovery Partition Creator.app” and choose “Open” to bypass Gatekeeper
> 4. Follow the onscreen instructions, and select the primary drive you want to restore a recovery partition onto (typically Macintosh HD unless you named the drive differently, or are using a separate disk)
>      Make Recovery Partition on Mac
> 5. Point to the Mac OS X installer application you downloaded in the first step and let the AppleScript do it’s work
> 6. When the Recovery Partition Creator app is finished running, reboot the Mac and hold down Command+R to boot into Recovery and confirm the recovery partition now exists and works as intended

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted that cloning with Disk Utility will not include recovery partition. Recovery Partition Creator 4.x is the right tool for you to create a recovery partition: http://musings.silvertooth.us/downloads-2/ .